# Is it advisable to have a web browser remember login credentials?

Tags: passwords, web-browser, access-control

I have a really long random password for my cellphone account and have it written down in a safe place. I only use it once a month and am considering having my browser remember it. Would there be any disadvantages to this? My computer is password protected so I don't see the threat.

Something I want to point out: the longer a password is the more likely a person is to make a mistake typing it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you use a strong [Master Password](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Master_password), and don't forget it or lose it (Because resetting your master password will remove all of your saved usernames and passwords).

Essentially doing this means you're using Firefox as a password manager. The question now is "Is Firefox a good password manager?". [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/20168/how-safe-is-firefox-password-manager) [are](https://superuser.com/questions/416275/how-safe-is-the-password-manager-in-browsers?rq=1) [some](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords) answers to consider.

Alternatives: Lastpass (as mentioned) is a standalone password manager. A free and open source one I use is [Keepass](http://keepass.info/).

Answer (score 1):

This greatly depends on the web browser.

e.g. Firefox had some [trouble](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=360493) with their password manager's security in the past.
I don't know about other browsers though...

If you want to be browser-independent you can use a service like https://lastpass.com/ They have plugins for most browsers. They even have a on screen keyboard.

Of course you should also choose a good master password for whatever password safe you are going to use.

Comment: "_Firefox had some trouble with their password manager's security in the past._" in the linked discussion many people have argued that this is not a Firefox issue at all. In particular see [this comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=360493#c93) "This is not really a flaw, The password managers (both in firefox and ie7) are doing exactly what they are supposed to do, they are automatically filling in login forms. They simply fill out the fake form, it's up to the user to submit it!"

Comment: And then there's Javascript...

Answer (score 0):

What Tie-fighter said but really the question is would you be satisfied with the protection. A virus can steal your password but keyloggers virus could as easily steal you typing it in (so virus may not be a consideration). Is this a laptop? Do you think anyone would steal it and copy your HD contents (as oppose to selling it for quick $$ or formating to use for themselves). I think you would be fine. No one is going to guess your password which is important.

Comment: Lastpass has a virtual keyboard if you are worried about keyloggers.

Comment: @Tie-fighter +1. What about the master password to unlock lastpass?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Tie-fighter: Before you can access your passwords within lastpass you need some kind of password to unlock it? A keylogger can log that then if its designed, take all the passwords with in the program.

But i pretty much say all bets are off if you system is infective and all bets of not having it infective if someone has physical access to the HD

Comment: Like I said, Lastpass has a on screen keyboard if you are worried about keyloggers. Of course this does not help against other types of malware (e.g. stealing cookies). https://lastpass.com/?sk=1